# Azure Blob Storage - Set an alert when a new uploaded file is greater than your size limit

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Azure Blob Storage - How to set an alert inside azure portal when a new uploaded file is greater than my size limit? i.e if someone upload 500mb file by hitting upload endpoint directly i want to get alert to prevent high billing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to set an alert when a new uploaded file is greater than my size limit?

We could check the file sizes before upload to azure blob action. We could do that with javascript easilly in the client side.

Demo code:

```
if (typeof FileReader !== "undefined") {
    var size = document.getElementById('myfile').files[0].size;
    // check file size
}
```

**Updated:**

> if someone upload 500mb file by hitting upload endpoint directly i want to get alert to prevent high billing.

Based on my experience, it is not recommonded to check it after it is uploaded.
Becasue it has been uploaded to azure storage. Suggestion way is that you limit it on the client side.

Now it is not supported to add the alert rule for storage resource. If you still stick to doing that,you could use [Azure function with blob trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob) to do that. You also could give your [idea](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage) to Azure storage team

```
[FunctionName("BlobTriggerCSharp")]        
public static void Run([BlobTrigger("samples-workitems/{name}")] Stream myBlob, string name, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
   //add you logicial here.
}
```

[image]

Comment: What does `people can hit blob endpoint directly` mean? Would you mind sharing reproduced demo code about it?

Comment: Sorry Tom, Wrong comment. It was for another question.

Comment: I just updated the question. more clear now. Im looking for alert inside azure portal. Thanks again.

Comment: It is not supported currently. I have updated the answer, detail please refer to it.